# Adserving Service for specific ads

Tags: advertising

I am looking into adserving services for a web application that is in development. I know there are the regulars like AdSense, DoubleClick, etc but the client wants the ability to sell of sections of the website to specific advertisers for specific campaigns. I would really prefer not to write this functionality (add, change, set duration, etc) from scratch so I'm looking for an adserving service that will allow specific ads to be uploaded and displayed to the end user. Preferably, one that integrates with a CDN of somesort.

Are there services that offer this functionality?

Comment: There is software that allows you to sell advertising directly on your website. This is a good option in conjunction with an ad network, however, it can be hard to sell all of your space yourself. This site does not allow questions that are asking for recommendations. This is because the answer would be opinion based and the site may be abused for spam.

Comment: Okay so what if I'm looking for opinions? I have no idea what services are available and it's not like there is a simple Google search term I can use as this seems to be a very niche market. Where should I ask so that this doesn't get closed out?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is http://www.revive-adserver.com/

This is a fork off the old OpenX code base before it was sold. It can section your website off into different sell-able regions and the like. This will be the best starting point for what you are looking to do.